# website developed with codeigniter working well on localhost but internal server error 500 on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am newbie to codeigniter i am developed a website from past few days. The website working well on the localhost.but when i tested that that website on live web server i gives out following error:

500 - Internal server error.
    There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
     i tried a lot of things like .htaccess solutions available on different tutorials but not successful. Then i tried my self debugging and found that when i comment out the model loading line my index page get loaded without that data to have to get from the db.But as soon as i remove comment from that line it again gives me the same error. Then i checked my model i wont find any such problem.Now i am not using any .htaccess.
    PHP version on server:5.2.17
    codeigniter version:CodeIgniter_2.1.4

------------------------My code for controller is---------------------------------

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
    <?php 

    class video extends CI_Controller
    {
    function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('video_model');
            $this->load->helper('html');
            $this->load->library('session');
        }
    function index()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('searchterm');
        $data['latest_video']=$this->latest_video();
        $data['uk_video']=$this->uk_video();
        $data['hm_video']=$this->hm_video();
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }
    function watch()
    {
        $v_type=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $v_id=$this->uri->segment(4);
        if($v_type && $v_id)
        {
        $data['multiple_videos']=$this->video_model->get_all_videos($v_type);
        $data['single_video']=$this->video_model->get_single_video($v_id,$v_type);
        $counter= $data['single_video'][0]['counter'];
        $id= $data['single_video'][0]['v_id'];
        $this->load->view('watch',$data);
        $this->view_counter($id,$counter);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('video','refresh');
        }
    }
    function latest_video()
    {
    $data[]=$this->video_model->get_latest_video();
    return $data;

    }
    function uk_video()
    {
    $data[]=$this->video_model->get_uttrakhand_video();
    return $data;

    }
    function hm_video()
    {
    $data[]=$this->video_model->get_himachal_video();
    return $data;

    }
    function result()
    {
        $this->load->view('search');
    }
    function view_counter($id,$counter)
    {

        $user_ip=$this->input->ip_address();
        if(!$this->input->cookie($id))
        {
            $cookie=array('name'=>$id,'value'=>$user_ip,'expire'=>43200);
            $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
            $counter++;

        }
        if($this->input->cookie($id))
        {
            if($this->input->cookie($id,TRUE)!=$user_ip)
            {
                $counter=+$counter;
            }
        }

        $update=array('counter'=>$counter);
        $this->db->where('v_id',$id);
        $this->db->update('tblvideo',$update);
    }

    }
    ?>
```

------------------------My code for Model is---------------------------------

```
<?php class video_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function get_latest_video()

    {
        $this->db->select('v_id,v_name,v_title,v_description,v_image,v_type,v_duration,v_time,counter')->from('tblvideo')->order_by('v_time','DESC')->limit(3);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $latest_data=$query->result_array();
    }
    function get_uttrakhand_video()

    {
        $this->db->select('v_id,v_name,v_title,v_description,v_image,v_type,v_duration,v_time,counter')->from('tblvideo')->where('v_type','uk')->order_by('v_time','DESC')->limit(4,3);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $latest_data=$query->result_array();
    }
    function get_himachal_video()

    {
        $this->db->select('v_id,v_name,v_title,v_description,v_image,v_type,v_duration,v_time,counter')->from('tblvideo')->where('v_type','hm')->order_by('v_time','DESC')->limit(4,3);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $latest_data=$query->result_array();
    }
    function insert_data()
    {
        $data=array(

            'v_title'=>$this->input->post('v_title'),
            'v_name'=>$this->input->post('v_name'),
            'v_description'=>$this->input->post('v_description'),
            'v_tags'=>$this->input->post('v_tags'),
            'v_duration'=>$this->input->post('v_duration'),
            'v_type'=>$this->input->post('v_type')
        );
        return $this->db->insert('tblvideo',$data);
        echo "data inserted";
    }
    function get_single_video($v_id,$v_type)
    {
        $cond=array('v_id'=>$v_id,'v_type'=>$v_type);
        $this->db->select('v_id,v_name,v_title,v_description,v_image,v_type,v_duration,v_time,counter')->from('tblvideo')->where($cond);
        $res=$this->db->get();
        return $res->result_array();
    }
    function get_all_videos($v_type)
    {
        $this->db->select('v_id,v_name,v_title,v_description,v_image,v_type,v_duration,v_time,counter')->from('tblvideo')->where('v_type',$v_type)->order_by('v_time','DESC')->limit(30);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

    }
    function get_video_list($limit,$offset)
    {
        $offset=intval($offset);
        $this->db->select('v_id,v_name,v_title,v_description,v_tags,v_image,v_type,v_duration,v_time,counter')->from('tblvideo')->order_by('v_time','DESC')->limit($limit,$offset);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

    }
    function get_total_number_videos()
    {
    $this->db->select('v_id,v_name,v_title,v_description,v_tags,v_image,v_type,v_duration,v_time,counter')->from('tblvideo')->order_by('v_time','DESC');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();

    }
    function video_edit($v_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('v_id,v_name,v_title,v_description,v_image,v_tags,v_type,v_duration,v_time')->from('tblvideo')->where('v_id',$v_id);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

    }
    function video_update($id,$table,$form_data)
    {
        $this->db->where('v_id',$id);
        return $response=$this->db->update($table,$form_data);  
    }
    function delete($id,$table)
    {
        $this->db->delete($table, array('v_id' => $id)); 
    }
    function user_authentication($u_name,$pwd)
    {
        $array=array('username'=>$u_name,'password'=>$pwd,'type'=>'admin');
        $this->db->select('username,password,id,type')->from('tblusers')->where($array);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    function user_data($u_name,$pwd)
    {
        $array=array('username'=>$u_name,'password'=>$pwd,'type'=>'admin');
        $this->db->select('username,password,id,type')->from('tblusers')->where($array);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}?>




  please take look at the problem thank you...
```

Comment: What does the servers error log say? And have you enable logging all PHP errors, warnings, notices and strict notices and then followed the error log? (you need to enable that in php.ini on the server to get the most out of it) - and find out what the differences in the PHP configuration are between your localhost and your server, that is not only the PHP version but also installed extensions and other settings.

Comment: i have tried to load only model and the data base then i get the following error:nable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\inetpub\vhosts\tv100.info\httpdocs\tv100.info\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124

Comment: i also enabled loging but log file is getting created there...

Comment: You just configured the database client configuration wrong. That's trivial. Double check you've got all needed credentials and connection informations (got them right?), if you'er unsure write yourself a test-script to try out isolated (in case you can't just quick-test on the remove shell of that host) and then if you did manage it to work, enter the credentials you know that are working into your CI configuration file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a database configuration support request with a third party software, here namely Codeigniter. No programming at all is involved.

Comment: i know that now this question off topic ,but i tried that after posting that question with the suggestion of friend. i have written all the database credentials right,because with all these credentials that database running well and good with core php

Comment: Well, what should we argue? I don't need to :) Your PHP is already arguing with you and despite the credentials you deem right it still throws you the error message in the face.

Comment: hmmm you are right ,,,,sorry i am little frustrated by this error . i had all the homework and its time to have reward for that but the ugly things comes in role........

Comment: Well, as written, the sky is not that dark, in the end this is trivial. It is only a configuration issue. Perhaps some codeigniter IRC channel or support forum has better interactive assistance at hand?

Comment: Your class name is wrong in the model it should start with a capital letter so it's "Video_model extends CI_Model" instead of "video_model" while file name should be kept all small letters.

Comment: thnx friend for your precious time give for this. I got my the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be a cause of a misconfigured .htaccess file on the root folder of CI.
Try using this for your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /mypage/test1   <-----MODIFY THIS
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also, go to config.php inside the config folder set it to blank.